# Get result with maximum values in multiple columns at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, max

Lets say we have a `DATES` table with 3 columns: `colYear`(YEAR), `colMonth`(MONTH), `colDay`(DAY).

Rows are inserted like:

```
colYear colMonth colDay
   1       2        3   
   2       3        0   
   4       5        5   
   4       8        0    
   1      10       28
```

I need to find maximum date based on 3 columns. So that in this example right answer will be:
4 years, 8 months and 0 days is maximum (we check years, max are 4s, after that we check months max is 8, so we've found our result).

Is it possible? How to achieve this with sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use order by -

```
    SELECT * from DATES 
    ORDER BY colYear DESC, colMonth DESC, colDay DESC
```

Based on your DB you can limit the row count to 1.

so for oracle use `rownum = 1`
whereas for mysql it will be `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Works just as i wanted, thank you for nice and simple solution.

Comment: i am glad it helped... also make note of what Sparky mentioned above if you need to limit your count to 1.

Comment: Sure ;) used top(1) before hes told. Thanks again.